# How to check if a list of links present in a text file are present in the project folder using a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a requirement for finding a list of urls/links in my project folder if we have a test corresponding to them. the below is my script. Now this is not printing correctly which link is not present in the folder. Where i am going wrong here? Please help

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hi this is a test"
file='deeplinks.txt'
while read line; do
    grep -sr "$line" /Users/id856795/myproximus-rn/src 2>/dev/null || echo $line
done < $file
```

my deeplinks.txt file looks like this:

```
myproximus://dashboard\ 
myproximus://products\ 
myproximus://products/MV\ 
myproximus://products/MV/ordering/[MPCUID of a Mobile option]\ myproximus://products/MV/settings\ 
myproximus://products/TV\ 
myproximus://products/TV/ordering/[MPCUID of a TV option]\ myproximus://products/TV/settings\ 
myproximus://products/FI\ 
myproximus://products/FI/settings\ 
myproximus://products/EP\ 
myproximus://payments\ 
myproximus://rewards\
```

Comment: Please edit your post, not in the comment.

Comment: hello @tshiono i have done the changes

Comment: Thanks. BTW what for the trailing backslashes at the end of lines? If the original file contains it as is, it doesn't natter.

Comment: Besides can you provide example of lines of `/Users/id856795/myproximus-rn/src`? In addition please elaborate about `this is not printing correctly`. What is your expected result and what do you get now?

Comment: @tshiono your question related to backslash made me think to remove it and hence thanks

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know your code works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can give grep a *file* containing the patterns. It's not necessary to loop.

I suspect the incomplete results are due to the presence of regex metacharacters (i.e. `[` and `]`) in the input strings. You can instruct grep to use plain-text matching.

```sh
grep -F -f deeplinks.txt -sr /Users/id856795/myproximus-rn/src
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I could figure out why the script wasnt giving the expected out. It was because of the backslash. It wasnt required and hence i removed it and the script now given desired out put.